# How can I search for players in the same wifi in Unity?

Tags: unity, networking

I am creating a game in Unity and I would like to create an ability for players to join the game that others have created on the same wifi. I would like it to be as effortless as possible(e.g. players don't have to find out their wifi, etc). The game is cross-platform - you could have one player on PC, other on Android device, etc.

Now I know that there is a game that has similar mechanism to what I would like to achieve: [SpaceTeam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sleepingbeastgames.spaceteam&hl=pl). Basically you select whether you use BT or wifi, and wait for other players to join.

How can I do this in Unity, or something similar that satisfies my needs?

Answer (score 2):

A UDP datagram sent to the broadcast address is delivered to all nodes on the LAN.

I don't normally do networking in C# but it should go something like this:
First, listen for packets with any destination address.

```
new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, ...)
```

Now, send packets to the broadcast address:

```
new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, ...)
```

These packets will be received by every machine behind the same router, via WiFi or Ethernet.

Comment: It would be far more elegant to find a solution with the Unity networking system, becaues that would integrate far better with the rest of the engine.

Comment: Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime.

Comment: You're always free to post a Unity specific answer, though!